# Calculate the total energey required to fly drone

Tags: batteries

How much energy will drone batteries consume if I have the following inputs,

By using provided GPS flight path data I've calculated total horizontal distance using Haversine formula, and multiplying this distance with provided horizontal speed I've **total horizontal flying time**.

By multiplying ascent speed with total altitude (considering starting altitude is 0) I've calculated **total ascending time**, and same way using the descending speed I've calculated **total descending time**.

By adding these 3 now I've the **total flight time**.

Now for further calculation I've following data inputs,

```
{
  "currentLoadInFlight": {
    "ascension": 0.020,
    "descent": 0.010,
    "translation": 0.015
  },
  "forcedLandingCharge": 200
}

{
  "verticalSpeeds": {
    "ascension": 5.0,
    "descent": 1.0
  },
  "energy": {
    "numberOfBatteries": 2,
    "capacity": 2000
  },
  "payload": {
    "additionalLoad": 0.1
  }
}
```

and details of these fields are as follows,

> #configurations
>
> - [verticalSpeeds][ascension] the vertical speed of the drone during an ascent in meter / seconds (m/s)
> - [verticalSpeeds][descent] the vertical speed of the drone during a descent in meter / seconds (m/s)
> - [energy][numberOfBatteries] is the number of batteries mounted on the drone
> - [energy][capacity] is the capacity of the battery in milli-Ampere Hour (mAh)
> - [payload][additionalLoad] is the extra load in in Ampere x Seconds ² / Meters ² (A.s²/m² ) caused by the payload (see
>   [currentLoadInFlight])
>
> #drones
>
> [currentLoadInFlight] in Ampere x Seconds ² / Meters ² (A.s²/m² )
> The current load in A per square unit of speed ((m/s)²) on the drone
> power system when it is flying
>
> - In vertical ascension [ascent]
> - In vertical descent  [descent]
> - In horizontal translation  [translation]
>
> ```
> NOTE: We assume that this to remain constant thorough the mission.
> ```
>
> [forcedLandingCharge] in milli-Ampere Hour (mAh)
>
> - When the available charge in the batteries is less or equal to [forcedLandingCharge], the drone will land

Now considering energy can be calculated using,

```
Energy = Flight Time x CurrentLoadInFlight x Speed²
```

How do I calculate CurrentLoadInFlight and speed parameter?